# How to create two columns with bullets using verbatim (as shown in image)

Tags: verbatim, bullets

[image]

I am trying to create a table like given in the image inside my thesis. On one column I have to write problem and parallel to that I have to give the solution. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are the bullets?

Comment: And where is the verbatim?

Comment: Does the table fit inot a single page or do you need a table that spans multiple pages? What did you try so far?

Comment: I mean I want to create a table like this in latex? when I create two columns the enumerates jump to next column. But I want to write solution on the right column. How to keep problem and solution parallel?

Comment: table can be span to multiple pages as I have to enter more then 20 problems and their solutions.

Comment: I am trying to create a table like given in the image inside my thesis. On one column I have to write problem and parallel to that I have to give the solution. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a three column table, one column for the number, the second for the problem text and the third for the solution text. If you need pagebreaks, take a look at `longtable` or `xltabular`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility, with `xltabular`, which combines `longtable` and `tabularx`, and`listliketab`, which is done for this sort of problems. Your row-problem-solutions will be referable, if necessary. However, be aware that, as all longtables, it can break across pages only between two rows.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath} 
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{listliketab}

\begin{document}

\storestyleof{enumerate}
\begin{listliketab}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\bfseries\thetabenum.}
    \centering
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}LX|X@{}}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Problem} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Solution } \\
\endfirsthead
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Problem}(continued)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{textbf{Solution} (continued)} \\
\endhead
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize to be continued} 
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
 \tabitem & Solve this first problem: \useshortskip
\[ a = b\] & And here is the solution to the first problem \\[-4ex]
 \tabitem\label{pb2} & This is the second problem & The solution to the second problem
    \end{xltabular}
\end{listliketab}

We see in \ref{pb2} …

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can We use something like this? \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
test code
here is some more stuff
172 192 d9a $^&2 ()%$
\end{verbatim}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{verbatim}
test code
yes more data here is some more stuff
\end{verbatim}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}

Comment: What are the  column(s) environment? And is verbatim doing in this context?

Comment: your solution is working fine thanks

Comment: Is there any way we could expand the width of the column? As the table is in the middle of the page and the page is blank from left and right?

Comment: Yes: you can nest in the `adjustwidth` environment (from `changepage`) which is done to modify locally the left and right margins. As the code above uses `\linewidth`, not `\textwidth`, it will adapt automatically. See the documentation  of the package for details.

Comment: Please can you tell me \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm} and \end{adjustwidth}  have to place after which line? I am confuse

Comment: After any line. Perhaps you have to begin a new  paragraph (blank line), though.  I don't know what your real table will be, but also think of the possibility of using a smaller font size  and reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` (6pt by default, which make 12 py per column). It can be reduced to 3pt without any problem

Comment: Thats working but on left side a lot of space is being produced. how to reduce left space using adjustwidth latex?

Comment: I don't see very well what you mean. Could you post a small compilable code reproducing your problem?

Comment: In the code given above i am putting \begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{2cm}. But in my text; each enumerate is of 10 lines on the left column and ten lines on right column. So the left and the right side is not justifiable. There is lot of space on the left side of the page and table is shifting towards the right side of the page.

Comment: I guess what you want for the second argument is `–2cm`. But please post a code reproducing this phenomenon.

Comment: it is even worst as the text in the right column is getting out of the paper

Comment: Without a code, I can only imagine the situation, but I have no crystal ball to solve the problem. Do you have the standard layout?

Comment: Can u please tell me how can i send a picture here?

Comment: I added a picture, please have a look?

Comment: I see., but I insist: to try solving your problem, we need a small, yet complete, code that reproduces the problem.